# Background Image in png not rendering with stackpanel quality

Tags: java, javafx

I assign a background image of my stackpanel that is transparent, but a weird border forms around the image, how do I remove that border? already grateful!

Code:

```
BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("android.png",110,110,false,true),
                BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                  BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);
            frontFace.setBackground(new Background(myBI));
```

[image]

And this is the result, you notice that the weird border forms around the button too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused pixels that should have been partial transparent on the borders.
If originally the background color *white* was taken as transparent color, showing a whitish pixel on a non-white background gives these kind of artifacts.

In Photoshop or Gimp one may use a magic lasso and have a 1 pixel border made really transparent. Or you could write code.